Mybatis pivot xml NumberFormatException "["
I am trying to create a variable column using mybatis pivot xml. It is like the example below.
However, if the string "[" is included, as in the example below, an error occurs.
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "test] It is Test1"
Mybatis
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT job
, deptno
, sal
FROM emp
)
PIVOT ( SUM(sal)
FOR deptno IN ('[test] It is Test1','[test] It is Test2','[test] It is Test3')
)
ORDER BY job
Works without problem in Oracle DB tools
The phenomenon only occurs within queries within Mybatis.

is deptno an integer (or any number types)?

deptno contains a string. The column name is incorrect.

Mybatis pivot expression
NumberFormatException "["
PIVOT ( MAX(CNT) FOR NAME IN

'${item.name}'


This may happen when 1) the result type is java.util.Map or its subclass and 2) a column label contains bracket [.
It is a known issue.
Since MyBatis version 3.5.16, you can make it work by writing a custom MapWrapper.
Here is an example implementation.
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.ibatis.reflection.MetaObject;
import org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.ObjectFactory;
import org.apache.ibatis.reflection.property.PropertyTokenizer;

public class FlatMapWrapper extends MapWrapper {
  public FlatMapWrapper(MetaObject metaObject, 
      Map<String, Object> map, ObjectFactory objectFactory) {
    super(metaObject, map);
  }

  @Override
  public Object get(PropertyTokenizer prop) {
    String key;
    if (prop.getChildren() == null) {
      key = prop.getIndexedName();
    } else {
      key = prop.getIndexedName() + "." + prop.getChildren();
    }
    return map.get(key);
  }

  @Override
  public void set(PropertyTokenizer prop, Object value) {
    String key;
    if (prop.getChildren() == null) {
      key = prop.getIndexedName();
    } else {
      key = prop.getIndexedName() + "." + prop.getChildren();
    }
    map.put(key, value);
  }
}

To use the custom MapWrapper, you also need to write a custom ObjectWrapperFactory.
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.ibatis.reflection.MetaObject;

public class MyObjectWrapperFactory implements ObjectWrapperFactory {
  @Override
  public boolean hasWrapperFor(Object object) {
    return object instanceof Map;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  public ObjectWrapper getWrapperFor(MetaObject metaObject, Object object) {
    return new FlatMapWrapper(metaObject,
        (Map<String, Object>) object, metaObject.getObjectFactory());
  }
}

To register the custom ObjectWrapperFactory, add the following line to the XML configuration.
<!-- fully qualified name of the custom object wrapper factory -->
<objectWrapperFactory type="pkg.MyObjectWrapperFactory" />

If you are using mybatis-spring-boot-starter, you can add the following line to the application.properties instead.
mybatis.configuration.object-wrapper-factory=pkg.MyObjectWrapperFactory


Is this a problem that will be automatically resolved if I upgrade mybatis version?
If so, which version is available?

No, you have to write the custom MapWrapper. In version ≥ 3.5.16, you can extend the built-in MapWrapper instead of writing it from scratch.
